# How to make smooth slide down navigation bar animation when I scroll?

Tags: html, jquery, css, animation

So, I want to make a Navigation bar animation.On my website my navigation bar has 80px height and it is in `position:relative`. I want to make a slide down animation after I scroll down more than 80pixels,and after this I want to set the navbar to `position:fixed`.

**Here is a short code for better understanding of what I did to this:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
      if (scroll > 80) {
        $(".black").css("position" , "fixed");
      $(".black").css("transition", "position 6s ease");
      }

      else{
          $(".black").css("position" , "absolute");     
      }
  })
})
```

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:1000px;
}
.black{
  position:relative;
  top:0;
  background:#333;
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  
}
.black ul{
  list-style-type:none;
  padding:0;
  text-align:center;
}

.black ul li{
  display:inline-block;
  width:100px;
  color:white;
}

.blue{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  background:blue;
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="black">
  <ul>
    <li>link</li>
    <li>link</li>
    <li>link</li>
    <li>link</li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, when I scroll down more than 80px,the navbar appears very fast, with zero animation and delay.I tried to add animation duration,and a bit delay, but for some reason it hasn't worked.
So I want to make a slide down navbar animation after I scroll down more than 80px and change the position to fixed,so after scroll down,the navbar will always be at the top of the screen.

**Now, here is a good example of how I want to make the animation(Copied from w3schools):**

```js
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-50px";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#navbar {
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: -50px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  transition: top 0.4s;
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<div id="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>

<div style="padding:15px 15px 2500px;font-size:30px">
  <p><b>This example demonstrates how to slide down a navbar when the user starts to scroll the page.</b></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

A big *thank you* to anyone who can help me in this,because I don't have too much idea on how I should do this animation.Sorry for the bad english,I hope you understand everything well.

Comment: Does not makes sense... scroll it up with the page for 80px just to, after 80px, animate it back to top 0... Please have a talk with your designer. BTW a mousewheel scroll-point is usually ~100px ;)

Comment: This is now built into browsers `position: sticky;` https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/